# Major difference between Angular 1.2.x vs Angular 1.6.x version

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-1.6, angularjs-1.2

I want to know the major difference between these versions like angular 1.6 supports UI router for routing and in angular 1.2 we have to use ng-route for routing

Comment: That's what the changelog is for: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md. The only different you list isn't correct. ui-router is not part of angular, and you can use it with whetever version of angular (provided its version is compatible).

Comment: AngularJS V1.2 is the last to support IE8. For more information, see [AngularJS Version Support Status](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/version-support-status).

Answer (score 5):

I would advise you to look at the post from Todd Motto :
https://toddmotto.com/angular-1-6-is-here

He is an Expert Developer at Google and covers every changes that happens in the Angular Stack.
Actually, you shouldn't only look at the changes from AngularJs 1.2 to 1.6 because between every minor version brings a slight change/approach to the framework.

> FYI, the versionning notation correspond to : Major.Minor.Revision.

However, here is a list of notable changes between 1.2 and 1.6 :

- angular.component() + lifecycle hooks
- ngAnimate (ngAnimateSwap..)
- Service / Factory
- ngRoute

Also, Here is the official documentation that list every changes between minor version migration : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration

Comment: I'm not looking for migration. I'm actually preparing a document where I have to specify why not to use Angular 1.2, as we are using an additional framework on top of Angular called westUI and higher version of Angular say 1.3 or 1.6 doesn't support WestUI.    I'm proposing a new approach all together where WestUI is out of concept.

Comment: @NikitaJain i need to do something similar in my company regarding upgrading angularjs 1.2 to 1.7, any chance you can share your findings?